# Array type inference shows weird compiler errors

Tags: swift, type-inference

I'm getting these errors:

> 'String' is not convertible to 'String?'
>
> 'Double' is not convertible to 'Decimal'
>
> 'Date?' is not convertible to 'Date'

In the following example

```
let someArray = [
    SomeBuilder.build(
        someString: "someString",
        someDecimal: 100,
        someDate: Date.make(2018, 8, 20),
        somethingElse: 0
    ),
    SomeBuilder.build(
        someString: "someString",
        someDecimal: 100,
        someDate: Date.make(2018, 8, 20),
        somethingElse: 0
    ),
    SomeBuilder.build(
        someString: "someString",
        someDecimal: 100,
        someDate: Date.make(2018, 8, 20),
        somethingElse: 0
    )
]

struct SomeBuilder {
    static func build(
    someString: String?,
    someDecimal: Decimal,
    someDate: Date,
    somethingElse: Int
    ) -> SomeModel {
        // do something here
        return SomeModel()
    }
}

extension Date {

    static func make(_ year: Int, _ month: Int, _ day: Int) -> Date! {
        let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        let components = DateComponents(
            calendar: calendar,
            year: year,
            month: month,
            day: day
        )
        return calendar.date(from: components)
    }

}

struct SomeModel {
}
```

If you add this as a fourth item in `someArray`, (It could be an accident in real scenario) you will see one of the errors above.

```
SomeBuilder.build(
    someString: "someString",
    someDecimal: 100,
    someDate: Date.make(2018, 8, 20),
    somethingElsse: 0
)
```

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve]. Your current code won't even compile and making the changes necessary to make it compile also makes the error you mentioned disappear.

Comment: Done. It is a weird xcode behavior and I was expecting someone with a similar issue have an exactly different code

Comment: That's still not a [mcve], since there are syntax error in your code. The `build` method is missing the `func` keyword assuming it is supposed to be a function, there's an extra `,` after the last input argument type and `make` is also missing a `return` statement.

Comment: Done. I cannot add all my code here but here are the steps to reproduce it.

Comment: There's no `somethingElse` input argument to the `build` function, so if you get rid of the extra parameter, the error goes away without having to use type annotation. The compiler error is misleading, you're right, but the issue you mentioned can only be triggered by calling a non-existent function (adding an extra input parameter to `build`), which is clearly a programmer error.

Comment: Apologies, I added it

Comment: And yes it is of course a programmer error. If you have a huge array, accidentally changing some fields, this error can definitely happen and the error is not very helpful. Doing my solution below, helps the compiler find the issue

Answer (score -1):

We found out that type inference is causing the issue and adding the array type helps the compiler find the exact issue if there is.

Solution:

```
let someArray: [SomeModel] = [
    ...
]
```